# get value from string java

Tags: java, arrays

I have this line

```
String tabledata = request.getParameter("tabledata");
```

and when I do

```
out.println(tabledata);
```

I get

```
[{
    "year": "2015",
    "org": "1",
    "sub_org": "2",
    "sub_org_amt": "1"
}, {
    "year": "2015",
    "org": "1",
    "sub_org": "1",
    "sub_org_amt": "1"
}]
```

**How can I get value of year?**

I tried

```
out.println(tabledata[0].year);
```

And i get `array required, but String found`

`UPDATE`

Tried

```
JSONArray newdata = new JSONArray(tabledata);


out.println(newdata.length());
out.println(newdata.getString(1));
for (int i = 0; i < newdata.length(); i++) {
    out.println(newdata.getString(i));


}
```

But I am getting

```
{
    "year": "2015",
    "org": "1",
    "sub_org": "2",
    "sub_org_amt": "1"
}
```

and

```
{
    "year": "2015",
    "org": "1",
    "sub_org": "1",
    "sub_org_amt": "1"
}
```

I want value of year I want my out to be `2015`

I used this. It will work

```
JSONArray newdata = new JSONArray(tabledata);


out.println(newdata.length());
out.println(newdata.getString(1));
for (int i = 0; i < newdata.length(); i++) {
    out.println(newdata.getJSONObject(i).get("year"));


}
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: @ Jens i would like to open the OP so that i can post my update as accepted answer it might help other people with same problem

Comment: @Sarseth can you help open the OP?

Comment: no sorry I cant. And even I dont know how. But anyway, it's not the same answer is as in linked question on top of this question? No need for answering same thing again ;)